# How to set filter only on country boundaries with US worldview?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm using Mapbox GL to color dynamically countries. Some of the countries are red, some are green.

For this, I'm using the country-boundaries-v1 source, then I use the iso_3166-1 data from country-boundaries to set a filter on the layers that use the country-boundaries source.

This is the code where I add my layers:

```js
addLayers (map, layers) {
  layers.forEach((layer) => {
    map.addLayer({
      id: layer.id,
      source: layer.source,
      'source-layer': layer.sourceLayer,
      layout: {
        visibility: 'none'
      },
      type: 'fill',
      paint: {
        'fill-opacity': 0.5
      }
    }, 'country-label')
  })
},
```

And there is where I make visible my layer, add the color and set my filter on a list of iso_3166-1 codes:

```js
map.setLayoutProperty(state.id, 'visibility', 'visible')
map.setPaintProperty(state.id, 'fill-color', this.layerColor(formattedState))
map.setFilter('positive-countries', ['in', 'iso_3166_1', 'FR', 'BE', 'IN', 'CN', 'JP'])
```

The problem is that when I add the 'fill-color' property on my layers that have reduced opacity, countries with different worldview (like China, Japan, India) therefore have layers that overlap. The result is that some countries, instead of having a layer with an opacity of 0.6, have 3 with an opacity of 0.6, which makes them opaque.

I tried to add this :

```js
map.setFilter('positive-countries', ['match', ['get', 'worldview'], ['all', 'US'], true, false])
```

Hope Mapbox only uses the US worldview, but it doesn't work.

Here is a screenshot of my map so you can see the problem:

[image: map]

As you can see, countries like China, India and Japan have multiple layers because there's multiple worldview for these countries, so they look different than others.

Does anyone know if what I want to do is possible?

EDIT:

I tried this:

```js
const filters = [
  'any',
  ['in', 'iso_3166_1', 'MA', 'BR'],
  ['==', 'all', ['get', 'worldview']],
  ['in', 'US', ['get', 'worldview']]
]

map.setFilter('positive-countries', filters)
```

But I got these errors:

```
mapbox-gl.js:31 Error: layers.positive-countries.filter[2][2]: string, number, or boolean expected, array found
mapbox-gl.js:31 Error: layers.positive-countries.filter[3][2]: string, number, or boolean expected, array found
```

If I remove `['in', 'iso_3166_1', 'MA', 'BR'],` there are no more errors but of course I have no applied filter on my map.

So, I tried this:

```js
const filters = [
  'any',
  ['==', 'all', ['get', 'worldview']],
  ['in', 'US', ['get', 'worldview']]
]

map.setFilter(params['id'], filters)
map.setFilter(params['id'], ['in', 'iso_3166_1', 'MA', 'BR'])
```

but the result is the same as without filter on the worldview...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone else is facing the same problem, this is the solution:

```js
const filters = [
  'all',
  ['match', ['get', 'worldview'], ['all', 'US'], true, false],
  ['match', ['get', 'iso_3166_1'], ['MA', 'BR'], true, false]
]

this.map.setFilter(layerId, filters)
```

Only the countries as seen by the USA are then visible

Comment: For some reason this did not work with my specific setup but I found an answer to a very similar question that did work... linking here in case it helps anyone else: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74558735/1081957