# Cannot combine multiple filters (ISO country codes)

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.nieknijland.nl/blog/how-to-highlight-countries-with-mapbox) to highlight countries on my Mapbox map (using the [Mapbox Countries v1 vector tileset](https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-countries-v1/)). However, some countries seem to be highlighted twice (i.e. their shading is darker).

Here's my map right now:
[image: map with Asian countries highlighted]
As you can see, China, India, etc are a more vibrant color than the other countries in Asia. (This is also a phenomenon in the Medium post, as you can see in the third photo in the "Add a layer" section.)

Here's my code:

```js
map.addLayer({
  id: 'country-boundaries',
  source: 'country-boundaries',
  'source-layer': 'country_boundaries',
  type: 'fill',
  paint: {
    'fill-color': palette.blue.flats,
    'fill-opacity': 0.4,
  },
  filter: [
    'in',
    'iso_3166_1_alpha_3',
    ...highlightedContinents.reduce((countries, c) => {
      return countries.concat(...ContinentRegionDefinitions[c].countries);
    }, [] as ISOCountry[]),
  ],
});
```

and the array being returned is just a list of 3-digit ISO 3166-1 codes (`['AFG', 'ARE', ...]`).

I believe the problem is that I'm showing all worldviews, so countries with disputed boundaries are being shown twice.

I can change the filter from being the country codes to [filtering by worldview](https://docs.mapbox.com/data/boundaries/reference/polygon-tilesets/#--polygon---worldview-text) (see bottom of docs page for sample code):

```js
filter: [
  'any',
  ['==', 'all', ['get', 'worldview']],
  ['in', 'US', ['get', 'worldview']],
],
```

and I get this, where almost all (except the circled) are only highlighted once:

[image: map with all countries highlighted]

Now, one would assume that, to get what I'm after, I could just [combine these two filters](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#all) like so:

```js
[
  'all',
  [
    'any',
    ['==', 'all', ['get', 'worldview']],
    ['in', 'US', ['get', 'worldview']],
  ],
  [
    'in',
    'iso_3166_1_alpha_3',
    ...highlightedContinents.reduce((countries, c) => {
      return countries.concat(...ContinentRegionDefinitions[c].countries);
    }, [] as ISOCountry[]),
  ],
]
```

but for some reason that doesn't work:

[image: map with no highlighted countries]

(I've tried removing the `...highlightedCountinents.reduce(...)` part and just replacing it with a short, static array, but that didn't help.)

Any thoughts? Is my filter wrong?

Comment: I ended up just using a different tileset following this guide: https://dev.to/wuz/building-a-country-highlighting-tool-with-mapbox-2kbh

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else stumbles across this I managed to get this to work with the following filter:

```js
let masterFilter = [
  'all',
  ['any',
    ['==', 'all', ['get', 'worldview']],
    ['in', 'US', ['get', 'worldview']],
  ],
  ['==', 'false', ['get', 'disputed']],
  ['any', ['all', ['in', ['get', 'iso_3166_1_alpha_3'], ["literal", countriesToShow.flat()]]]],
];
```